# ¿Como se usa la herencia de Java? en la opcion extends tengo un error para heredar otro objeto

Tags: java, clase, herencia, java-import

```
class CarroToyota extends carroBMW
 {
     public CarroToyota () {
         modelo= "Toyota";
     }
 }
```

La parte superior dice que es correcto pero al momento de hacer import a otra clase dice que tengo un error en ca.modelo:

```
import paquete.carroBMW.CarroToyota;
class Main2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CarroToyota ca;
        ca=new CarroToyota();
        ca.modelo;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Las 2 clases están en diferentes ficheros y como public ambas?

Comment: Varias cosas: en primer lugar, el nombrado de clases debería comenzar con mayúsculas (CarroBMW).  Segundo, "ca.modelo;" no es una sentencia válida en Java, puedes realizar una asignación (String modelo = ca.modelo;) o imprimir en pantalla el valor de la variable (System.out.println(ca.modelo);). Finalmente, deberías colocar el código completo (falta la clase carroBMW), ya que además de el error de sintaxis es posible que no puedas acceder al miembro modelo por la configuración de visibilidad (tus clases son package-private y dependería de si están o no en el mismo paquete)

Comment: @dddenis Concuerdo con marcos complementa tu codigo para poder ayudarte de mejor manera ya que esta forma estas intuyendo y quizas no te demos una solucion adecuada.

Comment: De carro Toyota tampoco está el código completo, no se ve dónde creas la variable modelo